# Textfield input formatter no longer work after I use TextEditingController

Tags: flutter, inputformatter

I am using [pattern formatter](https://pub.dev/packages/pattern_formatter) package in order to use `ThousandsFormatter`. so when I have value `10000000`, it will then automatically be shown as `10.000.000`. initially the code is like this, and it works as intended

```
TextFormField(     
     autofocus: false,
     autocorrect: false,
     maxLines: 1,
     textAlign: TextAlign.end,
     keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
     onChanged: (newNominal) {
         final newValue = newNominal.replaceAll(".", "");
         controller.selectedNominal = int.tryParse(newValue) ?? 0;
     },
     inputFormatters: [
         ThousandsFormatter(formatter: NumberFormat("#,###.##", "in_ID")),
     ],
),
```

and then I make some buttons like this

[image]

as you can see, when I choose $4000 then the Textfield will show `4000`, I expect it will show `4.000`

I use `TextEditingController` to populate the value in the Textfield after selecting the value from button, so my TeextField will be like this

```
final _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

TextFormField(  
     controller: _textEditingController, // I add this line   
     autofocus: false,
     autocorrect: false,
     maxLines: 1,
     textAlign: TextAlign.end,
     keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
     onChanged: (newNominal) {
         final newValue = newNominal.replaceAll(".", "");
         controller.selectedNominal = int.tryParse(newValue) ?? 0;
     },
     inputFormatters: [
         ThousandsFormatter(formatter: NumberFormat("#,###.##", "in_ID")),
     ],
),
```

when I tap one of those button and the `build` will called again, so I set the text in the textfield like this

```
@override
  Widget build(context) {

      final selectedNominal = pageController.selectedNominal.toString();
      final editingValue = TextEditingValue(
        text: selectedNominal,
        selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(
          TextPosition(offset: selectedNominal.length),
        ),
      );

      _textEditingController.value = editingValue;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Title here"),
      ),
      body: _buildWidgets(),
    );
  }
}
```

I don't understand why the `ThousandsFormatter` no longer work after `_textEditingController.value` , even when I type the number value using keyboard, the `ThousandsFormatter` also doesn't work

the nominal controller is like this

```
class NominalController with ChangeNotifier {


  int _selectedNominal = 0;
  int get selectedNominal => _selectedNominal;

  set selectedNominal(int newValue) {
    _selectedNominal = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to give separator first before assigning the string value to the textEditing controller

so I have to 'manually' set from `10000` to be `10.000` before assigning the value to textEditing controller

```
final selectedNominal = pageController.selectedNominal; // 10000
var currencyFormat = NumberFormat.currency(locale: "in_ID", symbol: "");
final formattedNominal = "${currencyFormat.format(selectedNominal).replaceAll(",00", "")}"; // 10.000

            
final editingValue = TextEditingValue(
     text: formattedNominal, // 10.000
     selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset:formattedNominal.length)),
);

_textEditingController.value = editingValue;
```